# Unable to shutdown, who to blame?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, hardware-failure, shutdown, reboot

My PC has always suffered from this problem: upon reboot, the power, instead of staying up and running until BIOS POST, most of the time (but not always, and that's why I don't think this has never been the intended behavior) "cutted off" like it was shutting down instead of rebooting, before "starting up" again. Let's call this a "fake-shutdown". This has never been a big deal, so I never returned either the motherboard or the power supply.

But now this issue got worse, i.e. 90% of the time I'm totally unable to shutdown the PC at all. Meaning that both from `Ubuntu` and from the BIOS Boot Menu, either shutting it down properly (from `Ubuntu`) or pressing either the power button on the case or the power button on the motherboard (from both `Ubuntu` and from the BIOS Boot Menu), the PC performs a "fake-shutdown" like described, but this time, leaving aside the weirdness of the thing, this is not even the intended behavior.

Surprisingly enough, disconnecting the power button on the case mitigates the issue, but doesn't remove it, i.e. the "fake-shutdown" still occurs upon reboot, even tough this happens let's say 20% of the time instead of 90% of the time.

My motherboard doesn't support Wake-On-Lan, and "Restore AC Power Loss" is set to `Power Off`, anyway from the escalation of this problem I believe the issue is actually a faulty component's guilt, either the motherboard or the power supply.

So my request is this: **can someone suggest a definitive test to spot which of the two is faulty? Or is there a third option?**

As of now, only the DVD-ROM drive is connected to the motherboard.

Any help would be really appreciated and a good definitive solution/good definitive way to spot which is the faulty component will be rewarded as soon as i can put a bounty on this question, because it would be of great help both to avoid potentially wasting money replacing a random component and to avoid potentially wasting time without getting this fixed, since i really need this PC to be up and running.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Dave That's so true, but honestly I'd prefer to avoid asking other people to lend me their PSU if possible, I'd prefer to try to solve this without bothering anyone first

Comment: @Dave Of course that's not what i meant, what i meant is that maybe a question asked on a specific site where everyone gives its contribution just for passion would bother anyone less than let me uninstall his/her PSU from his/her working PC for a day

Comment: @kos - You are going to have to try and replace the PSU.  You are in a better position to narrow down what might be the problem.  This cannot be solved unless your willing to replace the hardware and eliminated possible causes.

Comment: @Dave Anyway don't get me wrong, there's no intend to put this community after anyone else at all, i just felt (maybe being wrong) that this should have been the first place to ask, because i love SE and because i love being a part of the community itself

Comment: @Ramhound I tought so, i hoped someone could have come out with some fix/definitive test to do before going ahead and either asking someone for a PSU or RMA the current one. I'll borrow a PSU as suggested by Dave

Comment: @kos - We don't have the system in front of us.  For me personally I would have to actually see the problem in person to provide a guess.  At this point your explanation of the problem and your conclusion sounds plausible.  But even if I was in front of the problem I would have to eliminated the possible causes.

Comment: @Ramhound I understand what you're saying, and i agree with that. I hoped that I was wrong in thinking that the only solution in order to exclude one of the two would have been replacing one itself, mainly because of the trouble i might experience both in finding a replacement for free and in installing it, not to talk about possibly waiting for the RMA time, but it seems like i have no choice. Thanks to everyone for your time

Comment: @Dave Yes i understood that you understood (forgive the cachophony) but i feared that my comment could have been really mistakenly interpetred like "Let's bother those guys instead of the people i know in real life", and i wanted to distance myself from supposedly having said something like that, so the real concern was more about my own comment, and i wanted to clarify that. Yes, you're probably right, as i said to Ramhound i hoped there could have been an easier way, but it looks like i'm out of luck. Thanks again for your responses

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a tool for such a thing.

In this instance the easiest (and cheapest) approach is to simply borrow a PSU. You can then see if this has any impact (or not). If not, then (and I'll assume you've tested with 1 RAM chip only (just for completeness) it's most likely the motherboard (or some part of the board at least).

Answer (score 0):

we just had the same issue last week, I put out all components and tested em all on a good PC one by one, found out the motherboard was the cause. There are some utilities that can give u some basic into about all components in your PC, but they can't tell the health status about those parts. The best way to find out which part is damaged is to try em on other PC one by one if you don't know some basic symptoms of failing parts.